# How to copy paste certain columns into another excel sheet and repeat for every sheet with the same name?

Tags: vba, excel

So I have tried some of the solutions on this question, but I am still finding issues. My experience to VBA is also quite limited, but I understand functions etc.

**The problem description:**
I have two excel docs, one called part 1 and the other part 2. Each part consists of 280 tabs called T1-T280. Documents are identical, but only half of each document could get processed and now need to be consolidated.

**I want to automate a method with VBA to copy columns AZ to CI from part 2 into part 1 corresponding to the T number (e.g. T20's AZ to CI from part 2 needs to pasted on part 1's T20's AZ to CI).**

If I can manage the above I want to extend this function to allow for 5 parts. (I just want to know how to add the reference to these as well and how to specify the range function). Is it easier to do this in a repeater function?

Answer (score 0):

```
for each worksheet in part_2
    with worksheet
        .range(.columns(52), .columns(87)).copy _
                Destination := part_1.worksheets(worksheet.name).columns(52)
    end with
next worksheet
```

Iterate through all worksheets of part_2, copy desired columns and paste them in part_1.